# A man without eyes

Tags: riddle, wordplay

A man without eyes saw pears on a tree; he did not take pears, he did not leave pears; how can that be?

Answer (score 9):

The usual answer to this very old riddle is that

> the man had *one* eye, took *one* pear and left *one* pear.

I have to say that

> I would not say that someone with one eye is "without eyes"; that's not how the word "without" works. Nor would I say that someone who takes one thing "does not take" whatever it is, and likewise for leaving. So this riddle is, for me, in [xkcd 169](https://xkcd.com/169/) territory.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Gareth I'll keep that in mind for further questions.

Comment: XKCD 169 should be in the help centre for Puzzling SE :-)

Comment: I don't know. Seems to be the whole point of the cryptic-crosswords tag.

Comment: I'd say this riddle is valid on a technical basis.  "pears" can indicate a set of pears with more than one element.  If there is only one pear, then it cannot contain a set of pears with more than one element.  Similarly, if a man has only one eye, he has an eye, but arguably, not "eyes".